# How to get child span using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, replace, find, html

I have a structure like below:

```
<span class="IN-widget">
    <span>
        <span class="IN-top">
            <span class="IN-top">
                <span class="IN-top" >
                    <span class="IN-top">
                        3
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <br/> 
    <span>
        <span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span>
                    in
                </span>
                <span>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        Share
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to Replace the "Share" with "Not Shared". I have tried the below code and using it i am getting "InShare".

```
$(window).load(function () {
        alert($('.IN-widget').children('span').eq(1).text());
    });
```

Please help me how can i do this.

Comment: why are you using too much span

Comment: why don't you use any class or id over the element and try to replace that.

Comment: @Shekhar it is dynamically generated from third party..

Comment: if it is dynamic how do you know where that span will be every time? is it always gonna be the same structure?

Comment: Try `$('.IN-widget').find('span:Contains("Share")').not(':has(*)').text('Not');`

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark that are fixed always

Comment: @ArunPJohny please put your code as answer so that i can accept it as answer .. it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.IN-widget').find('span:contains("Share")').not(':has(*)').text('Not');
```

Comment: @Visions was a typo... fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('.IN-widget a').children('span').children('span').eq(1).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter to find the element which contains "Share":

```
$(".IN-widget span").filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).html()) === "Share"; 
}).text("Not Shared");
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPWZX/1/)